# Break table-cell rule for one row in css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have table made from `<div>` and `display:table-row` and `table-cell` and `position:relative`.
First row in table is like below

```
<div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell; position:relative; width: 25% !important;"><strong>Unit price</strong></div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; position:relative; style="width: 25% !important;"><strong>Price basis</strong></div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; position:relative; style="width: 25% !important;"><strong>Delivery date</strong></div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; position:relative; style="width: 25% !important;"><strong>Amount</strong></div>
</div>
```

Next rows have these format, but for one inside them I want to have only one table-cell with width on whole row (100%).

```
<div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell; position:relative; width: 100% !important;"><strong>some value</strong></div>
</div>
```

Problem is that text is wrapping on width of first table cell (25%).

How I should set this row to expand text on whole row?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll want to use is colspan, also you may want to use css rather than inline styling.

```
<td colspan="5">this should go as long as the tables width and not 25%</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

display: table-row doesn't make the row full of 100%. And the style in 3 last cells of first row is incorrect.
Try this

```
<div style="display:list-item;">
    <div style="width: 25% !important; float: left"><strong>Unit price</strong></div>
    <div style="width: 25% !important; float: left"><strong>Price basis</strong></div>
    <div style="width: 25% !important; float: left"><strong>Delivery date</strong></div>
    <div style="width: 25% !important; float: left"><strong>Amount</strong></div>
  </div>
 <div style="display:list-item;">
      <div style="width: 100% !important;"><strong>some value</strong></div>
  </div>
```